# Change Email keep gamertag Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Does anyone now if it’s possible to change your email address but keep the gamertag in minecraft PE on iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the email on your Xbox account.

From [the help article](https://beta.support.xbox.com/help/Account-Profile/manage-account/change-email-sign-in-for-microsoft-account):

> **Remove an existing alias on your Microsoft account**
>
> **Warning** When removing an email alias that’s a Microsoft domain (such as @Outlook.com, @Live.com, or @Hotmail.com), that email is completely deleted from our systems and can no longer be used to send or receive emails. It won’t be available for use again as an alias on another account. Microsoft does not recycle email addresses, so it may not be reclaimed at a future time.
>
> 1. [Sign in to your account](https://account.microsoft.com/?refd=support.xbox.com) using your existing alias and password.
> 2. Go to **Your info** at the top of the page.
> 3. Select **Manage how you sign in to Microsoft**.
> 4. Select the alias that you want to remove.
>
>    - If it’s a primary alias, you’ll need to select a new primary before you can remove the old one. To do so, select one of the other aliases on the account and select **Make primary**.
>    - You’ll use this new primary alias to send and receive emails, access your email accounts, and appear on devices
> 5. To remove the email address or phone number you no longer want, select **Remove** next to it and then follow the instructions provided.
>
> **Add a new alias on your Microsoft account**
>
> 1. [Sign in to your account](https://account.microsoft.com/?refd=support.xbox.com) using your existing alias and password.
> 2. Go to **Your info** at the top of the page.
> 3. Select **Manage how you sign in to Microsoft**.
> 4. You may be asked to verify your account before changes can be made. Follow the instructions provided to select your alias:
>
>    - Select **Add email**. You can create either a new Outlook.com email address or add an address that you already have. Then, select **Add alias**. You’ll be returned to the previous screen. Select **Verify** and follow the instructions provided.
>    - Or, select **Add phone number**. Enter the phone number you want to use, and then select **Next**. When you add a new phone number, we'll send a text message to that number to verify it. Enter the code in the text message, and then select **Next**.
>
>      > **Note** Email addresses and phone numbers that are already an alias on another account can’t be used.